# Problem updating miktex - arctrl-bin

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, updating

My miktex (32 Bit) 2.9 installation (on windows 7, 64 Bit) doesn't update (GUI and console).
I recognized the problem first on 2013-07-01. It seems to be caused by the package `miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9` as the following lines from an elevated shell show.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>mpm --admin --update-db --verbose --install=miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9
downloading http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma...
677286 bytes, 2449.67 KB/Sec
updating package definition directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tpm\packages")...
installed 136 package definition files
visiting repository http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
134749 bytes, 1356.61 KB/Sec
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
lightweight database digest: 348d5562d8a8cb8e92530ca19eba0eb1
going to download 21784 bytes
going to install 6 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9.tar.lzma...
21818 bytes, 213.07 KB/Sec
visiting repository http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
repository type: remote package repository
loading lightweight database...
downloading http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
134749 bytes, 1144.27 KB/Sec
lightweight database digest: 348d5562d8a8cb8e92530ca19eba0eb1
mpm: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:
mpm:
mpm: C:\Users\EBELIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\mikEC80.tmp
```

I already tried to remove the (earlier existing but outdated) package `miktex-arctrl-bin-2.9` but update and install fails. Cleaning the Temp storage directory and checking for file permissions there (temp) and in the install folder doesn't help.
Is there a solution without new installation?

Changing the repository to `...uni-erlangen...` did not help - it results in the following screenshot: [image: Screenshot after using uni-erlangen-erpo]

Comment: If the package is defective on the server a new installation would probably not help. But I made an update on another PC two days ago and had no problems. Did you try another repository?

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, thank you for the idea. I did - without success. I'll post a screenshot in the question - showing an initex-error after switching to the uni-erlangen-repo.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @UlrikeFischer, I tried around with changing the repository.

Via the GUI I got no chance - but running `mpm` from the console **five** times always with other errors (like timeout and file verifications errors) it finally went fine. Thanks.